# how save 2d arrays using pandas.DataFrame.to_csv in txt file

Tags: python, pandas

I have text files with two columns , I have manipulated the data as you see in the script,  and created a new 2d array.
now I want to save the new data in to a text file using pandas.DataFrame.to_csv instead of csv file , is there any easier way to do that?

Second question would be that if you look at the if state "if file[:6] == 'BS2913'and file[12] == '9':"
in the second argument, there is number "9", that represents different measurement data from 1 to 10 (like 1.text, ... 9.text), is there any way to loop through file names from 1 to 9 with a single run of the script?

if you could suggest some tips, I would really appreciate your help. Thanks

script:

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import errno

ev_corr = 'C:/Users/Py/power dependence/corr'        # creates a text file for  evaluations
os.chdir('C:/Users/Py/power dependence')  

for file in os.listdir():


    if file[:6] == 'BS2913'and file[12] == '9':     # select measurement data (1 to 10)
        print(file)
        data = pd.read_csv(file, sep='.', delimiter='\t', skiprows=12, header=None)  

        # correction for 1200 Grating
        nm_corr = 0.25*(data[0]-533.33) + 463.92   # calibrate the nm in 1200 Grating
        eV = 1240 / nm_corr

        #  subtract the background 
        sub_bg = data[1] - 1005

        #pandas DataFrame from list using zip
        # get the list of tuples from two cols and assign data to tuples

        data_new = list(zip(eV,sub_bg))
        data_corr = pd.DataFrame(data_new)

        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(ev_corr)):
            try: 
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(ev_corr))
            except OSError as exc: 
                if exc.errno != errno.EOFError:
                    raise  

        #np.savetxt(ev_corr, new, fmt='%.3f', delimiter = ' ')

        data_corr.to_csv('test.csv', header = False, index = False)

print("Have a fun")
```

output sth like this:

671.886 1015.000
671.618 1008.000
671.350 1007.000
671.082 1005.000
670.814 1005.000
665.722 1006.000
...
...
671.886 1015.000
671.618 1008.000
671.350 1007.000
671.082 1005.000
670.814 1005.000
670.546 1006.000
670.278 1005.000
670.010 1005.000
669.742 1006.000
669.474 1007.000
669.206 1006.000

Comment: Can you share the output format you’re looking for?

Comment: i don't know the right way to share a text file with two columns,

Comment: You can just copy/paste part of it, no?

Comment: I reposted the question with a 2d array with 2 columns.

Comment: it is solved...